# Anyone know an elegant function to fix name cases?

Tags: php

Kindergarten 101 teaches some of us that: "The letters in your name should be lowercase, with uppercase first letters." Yet in this post-literate era, how people enter their names in web forms seems to depend on their mood, or solar flares or whatnot: All uppercase, all lowercase, mixed, upside down...

Philosophically, I say whatever! Occupy your name, who cares. But I have OCD clients that prefer to see data normalized, standardized, predictable. So I'm asking you guys if you've seen any well-thought-out PHP functions for case-fixing names, that take into consideration the various exceptions that `ucwords()` would totally butcher, such as:

- Sven-Alex Crumpet
- Ronaldo McDonaldo
- Boopsie O'Brien
- J.R. Bob Dobbs
- Francesca de los Gatos
- YungCheng Li

Any functions out there that attempt to accommodate these alphabet rebels?

**UPDATE**
From Robin v. G.'s point of van-tage, there can be no script to rule them all. But I've decided that names entered entirely in lower or uppercase are likely candidates for a good scrubbing. So for these, I will do ...

```
    if ($name == strtoupper($name) || $name == strtolower($name)) {
        $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
    }
```

It would be easy enough to modify this to fix a few likely exceptions: dashes, apostrophes, 'McD', etc. Mistakes will be made, but who will complain? Not the meek bastard who entered their name in lowercase.

Oh wait, my name is in lowercase...

Comment: upvoted your question just for **J.R. Bob Dobbs**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply impossible.

Spelling of names varies from country to country, as you show in your question. The easiest way to go is to find the most common way of spelling, and that would be to capitalise every first letter of every 'word', i.e. every string preceded by a space, hyphen, dot or apostroph.

This doesn't fix all your problems (YungCheng, McDonaldo) and leaves you with other issues as well, but that's as close as you're gonna get.

Compare:

- Alex Van Halen (US spelling)
- Alex van Halen (correct Dutch spelling)

There's no algorithm fixing this.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%28Dutch%29#Collation_and_capitalisation) illustrates the problem with Dutch names very well, and that's just one language. There's probably an article like this for every language in the world. ;)

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered the van/Van imbroglio. I suppose one solution would be to check if an entered name was ENTIRELY upper or lower case, and only then run the name through some function.

Comment: Yeah, did you notice the 'v' in my username? I would hate it if something or someone uppercased that. Just doesn't feel right. You could indeed expand your logic to see if someone did enter any capitals at all and act accordingly. (Or tell your client this is impossible and probably cheaper to have it human-fixed.)

Comment: It is not impossible to ATTEMPT to accommodate the alphabet rebels, and that was the question!!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a try

```
$names=array();
$names[]="sven-alex crumpet";
$names[]="RONALDO McDonalDO";
$names[]="Boopsie o'Brien";
$names[]="j.r. BOB DOBBS";
$names[]="francesca DE LOS gatOS";
$names[]="yungcheng LI";
$names[]="mr hankey";
$names[]="santas little helper";
$names[]="j.r.r. tolkien";

$splitters=array(' ','.',"'",'-'); //more to come
$fixedNames=array();

foreach($names as $name) {
    $fixed='';
    $blank=str_replace($splitters,'?',$name);
    $n=explode('?',$blank);
    foreach($n as $f) $fixed.=ucfirst(strtolower($f)).' ';
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($fixed);$i++) {
        if ($fixed[$i]==' ') {
            if ($blank[$i]=='?') {
                $fixed[$i]=$name[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    $fixedNames[]=substr_replace($fixed,'', -1);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($fixedNames);
echo '<pre>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sven-Alex Crumpet
    [1] => Ronaldo Mcdonaldo
    [2] => Boopsie O'Brien
    [3] => J.R. Bob Dobbs
    [4] => Francesca De Los Gatos
    [5] => Yungcheng Li
    [6] => Mr Hankey
    [7] => Santas Little Helper
    [8] => J.R.R. Tolkien
)
```

It is impossible to "correct" a name like YungCheng without algorithms taking care of regional / cultural conventions and a huge name database to compare with.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a fairly old question now however:

```
function titleCase($string, $delimiters = array(" ", "-", ".", "'", "O'", "Mc", "Mac"), $exceptions = array("and", "to", "of", "das", "dos", "de", "do", "da", "los", "von", "van", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X")) {
    /*
     * Exceptions in lower case are words you don't want converted
     * Exceptions all in upper case are any words you don't want converted to title case
     *   but should be converted to upper case, e.g.:
     *   king henry viii or king henry Viii should be King Henry VIII
     */
    $string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
    foreach ($delimiters as $dlnr => $delimiter) {
        $words = explode($delimiter, $string);
        $newwords = array();
        foreach ($words as $wordnr => $word) {
            if (in_array(mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in upper case
                $word = mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8");
            } else if (in_array(mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in lower case
                $word = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
            } else if (!in_array($word, $exceptions)) {
                // convert to uppercase (non-utf8 only)
                $word = ucfirst($word);
            }
            array_push($newwords, $word);
        }
        $string = join($delimiter, $newwords);
    } //foreach
    return $string;
}
```

It won't work for YungCheng but it will work for pretty much anything else. The only issue is if the `$string` is ONLY a surname like "do Carmo" then it will return "Do Carmo". It is built for full names really so if you `$string = "frederick do carmo";` it will then return "Frederick do Carmo". Hope that is of some help.

Answer (score -1):

I found a decent library to handle various human names in different formats written in python called [nameparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nameparser/0.3.3). It still doesn't handle all the names listed above, but with some [configuration](http://nameparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customize.html) you might be able to get close.

I also wrote a short [blog](http://stevenandrewhunt.com/blog/misc/parse-human-names-with-python) describing how to get the nameparser library working from terminal. Maybe it will help somebody.

Here is the basic python script:

```
import sys
import json
from nameparser import HumanName

rawname = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).lower().strip()

name = HumanName(rawname)

# attempt to fix name title case
name.capitalize()

print json.dumps({
    'fullname': name.__str__(),
    'title': name.title,
    'first': name.first,
    'middle': name.middle,
    'last': name.last,
    'suffix': name.suffix,
    'nickname': name.nickname
})
```